# Similar Matrices - Matrix Multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How can we prove that $M  A^3 M^{-1}$ is equal to $MAM^{-1}MAM^{-1}MAM^{-1}$ where M and A are square matrices and M is invertible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with $MAM^{-1}MAM^{-1}MAM^{-1}$ and simplify using associativity, inverses, and identity:
\begin{align} MAM^{-1}MAM^{-1}MAM^{-1}&=MA(M^{-1}M)A(M^{-1}M)AM^{-1} \\
&= MA(I)A(I)AM^{-1}\\
&=MA^3 M^{-1}
\end{align}

Comment: You forgot to cube $A$ in the final equation.

Comment: @fibonatic: I did! thanks!